# Set custom pins for i2c on esp32

Tags: i2c, esp32

I'm trying to connect an E-paper display and an RTC module on an esp32 via I2C. However, my esp32 board doesn't have a pin 21, so I have to set another pin. It's also worth mentioning that I'm using the Arduino IDE to program the ESP

I tried changing the pins like this on setup: 
`Wire.begin(12,14,100000);`

But the pins didn't change

- How will I change the i2c pins?
- Is there any documentation on I2C on the ESP32?

This is the link to the [code](https://github.com/NickTheBit/programmable-smart-watch/blob/master/Firmware/arduino-build.ino)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, hopefully, someone finds the experience useful.

Inspect libraries that may be using the Wire library in your project they may be defining their own pins and such, overriding your choice.

A useful tutorial is [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-i2c-communication-arduino-ide/) it also contains this [function](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RuiSantosdotme/Random-Nerd-Tutorials/master/Projects/LCD_I2C/I2C_Scanner.ino) to scan for i2c devices